# User & Friend Permissions not showing up in the Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook, user-permissions

I am very much new to Facebook Connect feature. I dont know if its the right place to ask the question or not. I have made an app with facebook and requested the following permissions
user_about_me,
user_birthday and
user_hometown

When I click on ***Preview Current Dialog*** in ***Apps-->TestApp-->Auth Dialog*** I can only see "THIS APP WILL RECEIVE" "Your Basic Info". This is also the case when I log-in to my app through facebook. But when I click on "Preview Refferal Dialog" I see it correctly there. So whats the difference between the 2 dialog preview links? and what should I do so that I may ask facebook to return me additional data?

BTW, I am using Facebook Javascript SDK.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Guys any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I finally got the popup to show the correct permissions settings when I turned the "Sandbox Mode" to DISABLED, and I also accessed my app through `http://apps.facebook.com/myapp`.

For some reason, I still can't get the correct permissions to show up when I access my app's URL directly.